# RewriteRule [F,L] shows 500 in Apache log instead of 403

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-500

I am blocking bad bots in my htaccess file. Checking headers, I correctly see a 403 returned, but in my access logs, I see 500 instead of 403:

```
x.x.x.x - - [04/Aug/2020:10:56:02 -0600] "GET /testurl HTTP/1.1" 500 - "" "Yeti/1.0 (NHN Corp.; http://help.naver.com/robots/)"
```

Further, in Apache error log, I see:

```
[Tue Aug 04 10:56:02.896243 2020] [core:error] [pid 10430:tid 47402182534912] [client x.x.x.x:35589] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Sample portion of my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(bot1|bot2).*$ [NC,OR]
...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

These rules are the first to be processed, before canonicalization or https redirects. I don't understand why this is resulting in "10 internal redirects" per the error log.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As always when you see the http status 500 (server internal error) you need to check your http server's error log file. That is where you can simply read what the issue is instead of having to _guess_ ...

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The bad bot rewrite was redirecting to my 403 page, but since ALL files were included in the rewrite rule, that included the 403 page.  At the top of the RewriteCond list of bots, I included the following, which resolved the issue.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-403-page\.html$
```